# Cannot run the Threshold correctly Java

Tags: java, oop

Main.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{
    static Student[] students = new Student[10];//creates an array of 10 students to be entered

    public static int inputThreshold(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the Threshold: \n");
        int threshold = scan.nextInt();

        return  Threshold();
    }

    public static Student inputStudent(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter students surname:  \n");//instructs the user to enter a surname
        String name = scan.nextLine();//allows the user to input sdtudents surname
        System.out.println("Enter student score between 0 and 30:  \n");
        int score = scan.nextInt();//allows the user to input students score
        return new Student(name, score);
    }

    public static void printStudent(Student student){
        int percentage = student.getScore()*10/3;//retrieves the percentage of the score submitted out of 30

        System.out.println("Surname:  " + student.getName() + "   Score:  " + student.getScore() + "   Percentage:  " + percentage + "%");
        //prints out the surname, score and percentage achieved by the student
    }      

    public static void printThreshold(int threshold){
        int percentage = student.getScore()*10/3;//retrieves the percentage of the score submitted out of 30


        if (percentage < threshold){
            System.out.println("Surname:  " + student.getName() + "   Score:  " + student.getScore() + "   Percentage:  " + percentage + "%");
            //prints out the surname, score and percentage achieved by the student
                }
    }     

    public static Student getWinner(Student[] student){
        Student x = student[0];
        for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++){
            if(student[i].getScore() > x.getScore()){
                x = student[i];
            }
        }
        return x;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for (int i = 0; i = 1; i++){
            threshold = inputThreshold;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            students[i] = inputStudent();
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            printStudent(students[i]);
        }


        for(int i= 0; i < 1; i++){
            printThreshold(students[i]);
        }

        Student winrar = getWinner(students);//retrieves the winner from getWinner into a variable
        System.out.println("AND WE HAVE OUR WINNER! \n" + "Name:  " + winrar.getName() + "   Score:  " + winrar.getScore());
        //prints out the highest scoring students surname, with their score
    }
}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student{
   private String name;//sets name to characters
   private int score;//sets score to numbers
   private int threshold;//sets the threshold of the score
   private int max = 30;//sets max score to 30


   public Student(String name, int score){
       this.name = name;
       if (score <= max && score >= 0) //if the score is equal to 30 or less than 0
           this.score = score;//the score can be stored
       else{
           System.out.println("This number is too big ");//if it is larger than 30 it cannot be stored and shows errors message
           System.exit(1);//this will end the program
       }
   }

   public String getName(){
       return name;
   }

   public int getScore(){
       return score;
   }

   public int getThreshold(){
       return threshold;
   }

   public void setScore(int s){
       this.score = s;
   }

   public void setName(String n){
       this.name = n;
   }

   public void setThreshold(int t){
       this.threshold = t;
   }
}
```

Is returns Cannot Find Symbol - method Threshold()

I'm not sure what to refer to or how to call the method to get it to run correctly. Brief: 10 users, 10 scores. There's a threshold to be achieved by each entrant. The program outputs their names, scores achieved and the percentage of their score. But it should also announce the overall winner.

Not sure here

Comment: Change `return  Threshold();` to `return threshold;`

Comment: `return  Threshold();`  , where is `Threshold()` defined?

Comment: now cannot find symbol - variable student

Comment: You haven't defined a variable named `student`.

Comment: Fixed the Student issue. Now need to fix non-static method getScore() as it cannot be reference from a static context. Best practice for this?

Comment: The best way to avoid problems with static is not to use it.

Comment: With the threshold commented out the program will run fine, and correctly - just without the displayed winner.

Answer (score 0):

```
return  Threshold();
```

should be

```
return threshold;
```

Answer (score 0):

change `Threshold()` to `threshold`.

I strongly advice you to read this article before writing another program

[Objects, Instance Methods, and Instance Variables](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c5/s1.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static int inputThreshold(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the Threshold: \n");
        int threshold = scan.nextInt();

        return  Threshold();
    }   

 public static void main(String[] args){
             for (int i = 0; i = 1; i++){
                 threshold = inputThreshold;
             }
         ...rest of code in main
   }
```

`threshold` is a local variable defined in `inputStudent()`, you can't access it in `main()`  .Also `return  Threshold();`, there is no `Threshold()` method defined in the code you've provided